# generate set number of names used by shell split naming profile

Tags: python, alphabetical

ok so when you run the split function from terminal it generates the names it names all the parts starting with an x followed by an 2 letter alphabetical incremental pair.
aa,ab,ac ect.

What I am looking to o is generate a list of these names using python and a number.

```
n=3
#['xaa', 'xab', 'xac']

n = 5
#['xaa', 'xab', 'xac', 'xad', 'xae']
```

So far I am able to generate enough base numbers off of a number but need to find a way to change the second letter I append for every instance of 'z'

```
import string

n=30
myNum = round((n/26) + (0.5))
list1 = list(string.ascii_lowercase)*myNum

list1 = list1[:n]

list2sring=""
for i in list1:
 list2sring=list2sring+i+" "

newstring = "a" + list2sring.strip().replace(" "," a")
print("x" + newstring.replace(" "," x"))

#xaa xab xac xad xae xaf xag xah xai xaj xak xal xam xan xao xap xaq xar xas xat xau xav xaw xax xay xaz xaa xab xac xad
```

Desired Output:

```
xaa xab xac xad xae xaf xag xah xai xaj xak xal xam xan xao xap xaq xar xas xat xau xav xaw xax xay xaz xba xbb xbc xbd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string.ascii_lowercase`, `itertools.product`, and string formatting to do what you want.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from itertools import product

def make_patterns(n):
    letters_iter = product(ascii_lowercase, ascii_lowercase)
    return [
        f'x{a}{b}'
        for _, (a, b) in zip(range(n), letters_iter)
    ]

make_patterns(5)
# returns:
['xaa', 'xab', 'xac', 'xad', 'xae']
```

If you want it as one string for printing:

```
print(' '.join(make_patterns(5)))
# prints:
xaa xab xac xad xae
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split `list2sring` into list of chars and append it to string manually in the for loop

```
import string

n=30
myNum = round((n/26) + (0.5))
list1 = list(string.ascii_lowercase)*myNum
print(string.ascii_lowercase)

list1 = list1[:n]

list2sring=""
for i in list1:
 list2sring=list2sring+i+" "

chars = list2sring.strip().split(" ")
newstring = ""
i = 0
for c in chars:
    newstring += " x" + string.ascii_lowercase[i] + c
    if c == "z":
        i = (i + 1) % 26

print(newstring.strip())
```